# Canvas: DRM for websites?

Tags: html, drm

If you look at my post history, you will realize that preventing websites from being ripped has been a goal of mine lately.

Recently, I came across a game developed within the browser using Canvas and I was blown away by its graphics.

Now will it be feasible to render an entire website inside a canvas? If this is achievable, will this effectively make web page copying a thing of the past?

Comment: How does rendering in a canvas make copying harder?

Comment: @Scovetta The contents of the canvas is not easily retrievable.

Comment: @Sparrowcide but the code that *draws* to the canvas is just as easily copied as a web page, because it's just JavaScript.

Comment: If you can read it, you can copy it. You can make the copying harder but you can never prevent it. What "copy protection" attempts _will_ achieve, however, is more trouble for legitimate users.

Comment: Your quest is futile. You can't put information on the internet without people being able to copy it. That's just how the internet works. The only effective measure against people stealing your content is to get a lawyer specialized in copyright and sue the pants off of everyone who steals your content.

Comment: @cloudfeet right, but the JS can be domain locked and fairly difficult to retreive

Answer (score 2):

First of all: **you should not do this**.  It will:

- kill accessibility - e.g. screenreaders
- reduce responsiveness and require more CPU - particularly bad for mobile users
- require extra bandwidth (you'll need to load your own rendering code instead of using the browser's) - again, worse for mobile
- make it harder to adapt to screen-sizes (and high-res displays such as Retina), which will make your site look worse.

However, even if you wanted to (which you shouldn't), I don't believe it would protect you.  The code that is used to draw to the Canvas is still just as copyable as a plain website itself.